# Image Picker custom buttons React-native

Tags: react-native

Using custom buttons in the image picker, is there a way to make a button navigate to another screen?

`const options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  customButtons: [{ name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook' }],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};`

Comment: Ive solved... Its handled in the if/else statement in the callback